# With Rails Minitest, how do tests pass but fail when retested?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, foreign-keys, fixtures, deferrable-constraint

I'm using transactional fixtures in Minitest, my tests run successfully (and pass) when I first run them:

```
rake test test/models/number_test.rb
Run options: --seed 31462
# Running:
..
Finished in 0.271344s, 7.3707 runs/s, 7.3707 assertions/s.
2 runs, 2 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

However, when I immediately run the again, they fail:

```
rake test test/models/number_test.rb
Run options: --seed 22968
# Running:
EE
Finished in 0.058652s, 34.0997 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

  1) Error:
  NumberTest#test_to_param_is_number:
  ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  insert or update on table "calls" violates foreign key constraint "fk_calls_extension_id"
  DETAIL:  Key (extension_id)=(760421015) is not present in table "extensions".
  : COMMIT

  2) Error: 
  NumberTest#test_twilio's_API_is_configured_to_come_to_this_number's_URL:
  ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  insert or update on table "calls" violates foreign key constraint "fk_calls_extension_id"
  DETAIL:  Key (extension_id)=(760421015) is not present in table "extensions".
  : COMMIT

2 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 2 errors, 0 skips
```

I'm using [schema_plus](https://github.com/SchemaPlus/schema_plus_foreign_keys) gem to add foreign keys to my tables.

Because fixtures are loaded in alphabetical order, I'm using the `deferrable: :initially_deferred` option which only does the referential integrity check at the end of the transaction so all the data is loaded to all tables before the checks. This is what's made the first run of the tests to work… however I'm not sure why it's any different for the second run.

When running the retest, shouldn't all the database tables be emptied and fixtures reloaded using the deferrable option too? It's like deferrable isn't honoured after the first time.

To get it to work, I always have to run `rake db:reset` between running tests which seems crazy.

**Update 1:** If I comment out all the fixtures for `calls` (which actually have nothing to do with any test in `number_test.rb`), all works fine… I can rerun number tests as often as I like and they still pass. So, it does seem to be something with the deferral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a genuine referential integrity problem. `numbers` and `calls` both eventually link back to `users`.

Turns out, the `users` fixture didn't exist on the test server. That'd do it.

Answer (score 0):

Rails will try to disable constraint triggers in the DB to clean it up. You need to have the superuser rol to accomplish this. so do:

I enter `sudo -u postgres psql` and type:

```
ALTER USER yourdbusername SUPERUSER;
```